# Section for MWE while asking a question

Tags: feature-request

Recently a lot of new users do not provide a compilable MWE as part of their question because it is not mandatory.

This must be made mandatory by providing a new section for MWE as part of the question itself.

Comment: MWEs are really useful, but they are not required. There is a certain type of questions that does not need MWEs to be answered. For the suggestion see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6813/35864 and linked questions.

Comment: See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7749/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3386/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7489/35864 (your question, but the link is relevant for others as well)